# Jquery UI Tooltip is possible to have a icon and a title on it. At the examples are only simple texts

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

At http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138112/Tooltip
there is an example for M1 of a Tooltip with an icon and a title. 
How can you do this with current Jquery UI Tooltip?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by adding html tags inside tooltip using "content" option. Check this [JQFAQ.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-add-icons-and-title-to-jquery-tooltip/) topic which will explain you how to do this.

Comment: Your provided link is not showing the helping content related to the question. Can you please help me out? @Amar